# Universal Properties in google-analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am working with a client on their google-analytics  and we came across a question I dont have the answer to. The customer is using GA to pull conversion, bounce, ecommerce, and revenue numbers from their website.

They are looking at the Universal Properties for GA and wanted to know that if they make changes to the Universal Properties for GA will this impact how GA is pulling information from their website and recording it?

Thanks

Comment: This is off topic as it's not related to coding, but to comment, what do you mean "Universal Properties" for GA? Do you mean the Properties settings?

Comment: Might this be about a migration from "classic" GA to Universal Analytics ? I think this needs some clarification.